# Database design for multi level users with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design, associations

I have a database table for users which contains common fields like *password, email* etc. And there is also a field named `level` which defines user level such as *member*, *editor* or *admin*.

There is also some fields that specific for members, editors and admins which others don't need. So I think I should create separated tables for user types.

And here's the problem; **how should I approach this problem if I want to follow Rails way?** Both in terms of database design and associations.

Comment: you should be more specific about your needs. What are those extra fields ? Do you think you will need more "roles" later ? Cans a user have multiple "roles" at once ? At first glance, i'd say creating multiple tables for different user types is a bad idea : a user is a user, whatever its type, and you risk ending up with duplicates on separate tables. Another advice would be to look at some [authorization gems](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_authorization) to seek inspiration.

Comment: I also would not like to use multiple tables for users but a user type needs `points` field to make some actions while others not and another user type must have an association with `room` table but others. So creating `room_id` for each user while they don't need it, seems a little wrong to me. This is also true for `points` field right? So should I use multiple tables in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

seems you are looking for a role-based authorization system, coupled with specific attributes for each role. One way to achieve this would be with a data model looking like this :

```
.-------.1    *.------------.*     1.-------.
| users |<-----| user_roles |------>| roles |
'-------'      '------------'       '-------'
                     |
     .---------------+---------------------.
     |0..1           |0..1                 |0..1
 .--------.  .----------------------.  .----------.
 | points |  | some_other_attribute |  | room_ids |
 '--------'  '----------------------'  '----------'
```

this way, you ensure that all attributes related to a specific role are deleted if that role is removed from the user (by cascade delete).

You will have, though, to ensure that all your attributes models enforce validation rules like this :

```
class Point < ActiveRecord:Base
    validates :relevant_association?

  def relevant_association?
    user_role.role.title == "Admin"
  end
end
```

if your user can only have one role, you can simplify this by adding a `role` field on the model, and then write validation rules on optional attributes (that `belong_to` a user) accordingly. Still,the former model offers more potential for future adjustments (creating a new role is just creating a new record).

I'm not an expert on this matter though, so you can also continue to seek out inspiration ; the [declarative_authorization gem](https://github.com/stffn/declarative_authorization) provides an explanation of its data model that you may find interesting, too:

> ```
>                      includes                   includes
>                       .--.                        .---.
>                       |  v                        |   v
> .------.  can_play  .------.  has_permission  .------------.  requires  .----------.
> | User |----------->| Role |----------------->| Permission |<-----------| Activity |
> '------' *        * '------' *              * '------------' 1        * '----------'
>                                                     |
>                                             .-------+------.
>                                          1 /        | 1     \ *
>                                .-----------.   .---------.  .-----------.
>                                | Privilege |   | Context |  | Attribute |
>                                '-----------'   '---------'  '-----------'
> ```